# Is there a way to call `curio.spawn` from within `asyncio.run`

Tags: python-asyncio, curio

There is a [great library](https://geronimo-iia.github.io/async-rx/) that I want to use from a larger project that I'm working on that uses "standard asyncio". Some of the functionality of the library calls `curio.spawn` which results in an error when called from "standard asyncio". Is there a way to get this to work?

Example code that reproduces the error:

```
import curio
import asyncio

async def curio_method():
    await curio.sleep(1)

async def asyncio_method():
    task = await curio.spawn(curio_method())
    await task

asyncio.run(asyncio_method())
```

Result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/tmp/curio_test.py", line 12, in <module>
    asyncio.run(asyncio_method())
File "/usr/lib/python3.9/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
File "/usr/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 642, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
File "/tmp/curio_test.py", line 8, in asyncio_method
    task = await curio.spawn(curio_method())
File "/home/garyvdm/dev/image_builder/bpmagent/ve/lib/python3.9/site-packages/curio/task.py", line 613, in spawn
    task = await _spawn(coro)
File "/home/garyvdm/dev/image_builder/bpmagent/ve/lib/python3.9/site-packages/curio/traps.py", line 83, in _spawn
    return await _kernel_trap('trap_spawn', coro)
File "/home/garyvdm/dev/image_builder/bpmagent/ve/lib/python3.9/site-packages/curio/traps.py", line 32, in _kernel_trap
    result = yield request
RuntimeError: Task got bad yield: ('trap_spawn', <coroutine object curio_method at 0x7fc1b62eeec0>)
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'curio_method' was never awaited
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `asyncio.run`, you can use `curio.run`.

But, if you need to use `asyncio.run`, you can put your `curio.run` inside your `asyncio.run` logic. Anyway, I think that is not the idea.